# excel pivot table with different aggreagate functions

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have data set like

```
GROUP, ELEMENT, TIME
groupA, subA, .5
groupA, subB, .7
groupB, subA, .05
groupB, subB, .07
groupA, subA, .7
groupA, subB, .9
groupB, subA, .03
groupB, subB, .05
```

i want to create a pivot table that has GROUP and ELEMENT in the rows and the average times for each "groupelement" but the sum of the all element (averages) times.

```
groupA, 1.4
  subA .6
  subB .8
groupB .1
  subA .04
  subB .06
```

Currently I have the problem that group values contain the average of all group elements.

I found a way to separately set  the  group aggregate function to sum, but it then sums the whole data not the averages.
Is there any way to select different aggregate functions for the different levels that work on the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the result as your needs via "Group By" function in Power Query.

1. I split your data set via Text Value Columns in Data group, I choose the comma as delimiters.

[image]

2. Right click the result of above > Get Data From Table/Range, then follow the prompt to create a table.
3. After importing data into Query, go to Transform > Group By > Advanced > Choose **Group** to group data, then click "Add grouping" and choose **ELEMENT**.Give a name for "New column name", set **Average** for "Operation" and **TIME** for "Column".

[image]

4. After clicking OK, I get the data as following.

[image]

5. Click File > Close& Load to > Choose **PivotTable Report**. I also drag GROUP and ELEMENT in the rows, and get the Sum of Value.

[image]